# Choice requirement in defining Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, axiom-of-choice

In [this MO post,](https://mathoverflow.net/q/32720) the answers point out that the statement, "The reals are a countable union of countable sets" is consistent with $\textsf{ZF}$ (without choice). [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1243049) points out that in such models of $\textsf{ZF}$, Lebesgue measure $m$ as typically defined from its outer measure would yield $m(\mathbb{R}) = 0$, which of course is very bad. The issue, according to the answers in that question, is because the traditional proof of subadditivity for the outer measure requires Countable Choice $\textsf{AC}_\omega$.

However, I've heard that the statement "the countable union of countable sets is countable" ($\textsf{CUT}$) is weaker than $\textsf{AC}_\omega$. Is there, perhaps, a way to prove subadditivity of the Lebesgue outer measure $m^*: \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{R}) \to [0,\infty]$ given by
$$
m^*(E) = \inf\left\{\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n - a_n : E \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (a_n,b_n)\right\}
$$
over $\textsf{ZF + CUT}$ (i.e., no $\textsf{AC}_\omega$)? Or even better, can we recover subadditivity in models of $\textsf{ZF}$ where $\mathbb{R}$ *isn't* the countable union of countable? If not, is full $\textsf{AC}_\omega$ *required* to get the subadditivity?

By the way, I am aware of an alternative to Carathéodory's approach which uses Borel-coded measures (described in Fremlin's *Measure Theory, Volume 5*), choice free. I am simply wondering if we can ever recover the approach in $\textsf{ZF}$ alone/plus extremely weak choice principles.

Comment: Elliot Glazer is a proponent of the idea that the Lebesgue measure should be only assumed to be finitely additive to begin with, and with the help of some choice, expand this to show that it is $\sigma$-additive. Some disagree, but in either case, his approach will solve your problems more or less by definition. (See some very long, very interesting, and very elaborate discussions [on this MathOverflow thread](https://mathoverflow.net/q/393076/7206).)