# Topological properties of $[0,\omega_1)$ without choice.

Tags: general-topology, axiom-of-choice

Reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_uncountable_ordinal) wikipedia article, I arrived at the fact that $\omega_1$ can exist without choice. Since the proof I know of the fact that $[0,\omega_1)$ is sequentially compact depends on the fact that the countable union of countable sets is countable, I arrived at the following question:

> What topological properties of $[0,\omega_1)$ depend on the axiom of choice?

Comment: Is $S_\omega=[0,\omega_1)$? I have never seen that notation (it may be common, idk).

Comment: Yes, it is. I will change the title.

Comment: A countable union of countable sets is countable whether you take the axiom of choice or not, no?

Comment: As far as I know, you need at least countable choice to show that a countable union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: @AlexG That is wrong. For expample you can look [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/100717/zf-the-reals-are-the-countable-union-of-countable-sets-consistent). Note that the reals are always uncountable, due to Cantors theorem (no choice involved). Another place to look is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16246/the-cardinality-of-a-countable-union-of-countable-sets-without-the-axiom-of-cho)

Comment: Which properties did you have in mind?

Comment: @Alex: Not even remotely. There might not even be an upper bound, in terms of cardinals, to what sort of size a countable union of countable set is (meaning that it is possible that for every set $A$, there is a set $B$ such that $B$ is the countable union of countable sets, and there is no injection from $A$ into $B$).

Comment: @PaulPlummer and Asaf, thank you for the information and references. Math surprises me yet again!

Comment: @Asaf My motivation-property was sequential compactness, because I know that the argument I know won't work, but maybe there is another argument that does? But my question is intended to be as general as can be. However, it is to be noted that my knowledge of set theory is minimal, although my curiosity is big.

Comment: Maybe, to make the question more specific, you can ask as a reference request of results of these type,  plus a results on sequential compactness without choice. Although maybe with Asaf's answer it might be to\ late

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, yes. $\omega_1$ exists without assuming the axiom of choice. However it can be the countable union of countable sets, which can cause some troubles. Let me just point out that $\omega_1$ is, by definition, the set $[0,\omega_1)$. So I'll just use the shorter notation to make it easier.

So if $\omega_1$ is the countable union of countable sets, then it is the limit of an $\omega$-sequence of countable ordinals. Therefore it will no longer be the case that every sequence of countable ordinals has a countable limit. Therefore it will not be sequentially compact.

To see why this is true, if $\omega_1=\bigcup A_n$, where each $A_n$ is countable, there is a unique ordinal isomorphic [uniquely] to $A_n$. Now let $\alpha_n$ be that ordinal, and let $\beta_n=\alpha_1+\ldots+\alpha_k$. Then $\beta_n$ are increasing, and $\sup\beta_n=\lim\beta_n=\omega_1$.

For metrizability, the answer is that the axiom of choice is not needed to prove that $\omega_1$ is not metrizable. This is a combination of Corollaries 4.2 and 4.4 in the following paper:

> *C. Good and I. J. Tree*, [**Continuing horrors of topology without choice**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0166-8641(95)90010-1), *Topology Appl.* **63** (1995), no. 1, 79--90.

Comment: Great! Just a last inquiry... What about metrizability? Because with choice, an argument for proving $[0,\omega_1)$ is not metrizable is arriving at the fact that it is sequentially compact but not compact.

Comment: @Aloizio: Asaf will correct me if I’ve overlooked something, but it appears that if $\omega_1$ is the limit of an $\omega$-sequence of countably ordinals, then the space $\omega_1$ is the union of countably many clopen, countable subspaces. Each of these is metrizable, so $\omega_1$ ought to be metrizable as well.

Comment: @Brian: Why can you uniformly choose a metric on each ordinal?

Comment: @Aloizio: That's a good question, I'll think about it today and let you know.

Comment: @Aloizio: Yes, that looks like a genuine problem. By the way, another argument (with choice) for showing that $\omega_1$ isn’t metrizable is to use the pressing-down lemma to show that $\omega_1\times\omega_1$ isn’t hereditarily normal. Unfortunately, the pressing-down lemma requires at least some choice; Asaf may know how much.